# Why form class is highlighted as red?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Can somebody tell me which the cause of form class that highlighted as red? What's the meaning of this? I can't get rid of it. I already close the form at the end of the line. But when I view the page source this is what look like.

[image: SC]

Answer (score 0):

This is your editor trying to be helpful by highlighting the form tag.

As you're writing HTML make sure you're using an editor that supports more than PHP, like Atom or Sublime Text. Or tell your editor that you're editing HTML.